# Windows 10 unable to connect to PPTP VPN server

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I have set up a VPN on a Synology DSM 4.1 server. When I attempt to connect to the VPN with the Windows 10 built-in VPN connection tool, I get an error after login stating:

"Can't connect to PPTP VPN - A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for this connection was closed."

We connected perfectly the very first attempt, then after we logged off we were unable to get back on. I am using a Linksys e1200 router with port forwarding 1723 to the server IP, so I don't anticipate the problem is with the router. I can connect with a computer already on the network...that works no problem, but a computer off the network throws the error every time. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forwarding port 1724 isn't enough for PPTP, you also need a router that can, and has been setup to, forward GRE (protocol 47) inward to the VPN server.

Note: This is NOT "PPTP Pass-through", as that's for allowing multiple people behind the router to access outside PPTP VPNs.

From what I can see in the [e1200 simulator](http://ui.linksys.com/E1200/2.0.04/singleforward.htm), if you're using firmware 2.04 (or later) "PPTP" becomes and option in the Applications & Gaming -> Single Port Forwarding dropdown for Application Name.

I would suspect that using that predefined "PPTP" entry will also enable handling GRE, but it's not obvious, and I don't have one here to actually test with. :)

Beyond that, you may want to look into loading a compatible 3rd party firmware onto it (like, say, DD-WRT), which can/will give you more options for configuration.

Comment: I notice that the router firmware hasn't been updated since 1.0.03, and that the predefined PPTP option was not around then. I'll upgrade the firmware and see if the PPTP port forwarding fixes it. Thanks for the tip, I'll follow up on how it goes.

Comment: So, we actually weren't able to upgrade to 2.04 because we have hardware version 1, which doesn't support 2.04. Thanks for pointing out that we need to enable GRE in addition to 1724, I'm pretty sure that's the problem.